# Redirections from POST to GET in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5.7

I've form on my url localhost/projects/create ($_GET), and store-function is in url localhost/projects.

```
public function store(Request $request) {
    $project = new Project();
    $project->title = request('title');
    $project->description = request('description');
    $project->save();
    redirect('projects');
}
```

Why the redirect function doesn't work from lcoalhost/projects ($_POST, store-function) to localhost/projects ($_GET, index-function)?
I createt the ProjectController with a command "php artisan make:controller ProjectController --resource". I try from a video https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch-2018/episodes/10.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/redirects#redirecting-named-routes try to redirect to named routes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
return redirect()->route('projects.index');
```